# creating a listener that merge all finder windows

Tags: applescript, osx-yosemite

I want that every time I open a new folder it will automatically merge with the others finder's windows that are already opened. Basically one folder with n tabs.
I already use the command `Finder> Window > Merge All Windows` but I wish it was automatic.

All I can do is create an automation for merging the windows but it isn't automatic

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
            click menu item "Merge All Windows" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: You could run a script/app with a loop checking the number of finder windows. But this has to run all the time.

Comment: I know and I think it's not a good solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Finder’s preferences. There’s an option for that.

[image]

Comment: @Filmar23 Can you be more specific? I’ve been using that setting for months and it always worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to "Open folders in tabs instead of new windows" you might need to set View->Show tab bar, it does help for some cases, but still not always